# How to improve speed of 3-tier application?

Tags: performance, n-tier-architecture, 3-tier

My friend use to developed 2-tier application which application connect directly to database, now he need to move to 3-tier application but he has issue about speed of the application. This new application need to generate a lot of reports at client side so he worried about speed of this process which need to call to business layer to query data and then serialize back to the client, it take a lot of time.

He want to know, is it has a way to improve the speed of situation like this?

- Add information
  Generating report I mean query data from database (at application server) and serialize it back to client to bind it to report file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Generate the reports closer to the data, and download only the reports (possible zipped).

But make sure you confirm what the slow point is, before doing any work. (You can confirm it via logic, or running tests and counting numbers, or a combination of both).

Comment: Hi silky I have add more information on the question, forgive me for not enough information.